# How to show the custom icon on after installation electron application using electron forge

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

Thanks in advance.

I have developed one electron application. build process did by electron forge

Anyone has any idea on how to show custom icon on program and features instead of electron default icon.

```
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "packagerConfig": {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "executableName": "XYZ",
                "icon": "./src/assets/common/installer/xyz_app",
                "asar": true,
                "extraResource": "licenses"
            },
            "makers": [
                {
                    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
                    "config": {
                        "name": "XYZ",
                        "icon": "./src/assets/common/installer/xyz_app",
                        "loadingGif": "./src/assets/common/installer/xyz.gif",
                        "setupIcon": "./src/assets/common/installer/xyz_app.ico",
                        "setupExe": "xyz.exe"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZcD2.png)

Expecting to show custom icon on programs and features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Squirrel option named `icon`, rather there's `iconUrl` which requires an .ico file at an http(s) address.

https://js.electronforge.io/interfaces/_electron_forge_maker_squirrel.InternalOptions.Options.html#iconUrl